# How the product of two integrals is iterated integral? $\int\cdot \int = \iint$

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $\large{I} = \Large \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \normalsize e^{\small -\frac{y^2}{2}}\  dy$.

Then, my textbook says,

$$\tag{1}
I^2 = \left( \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \normalsize e^{\small -\frac{y^2}{2}}\  dy\ \right) \left( \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \normalsize e^{\small -\frac{x^2}{2}}\  dx\ \right) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(y^2 +x^2)/2}\ dy\ dx $$

I am not seeing how we reach the rightmost, iterated integral, and I do not remember the calculus how or why this works. Why can we restate the product of two integrals, each having funcions of  different variable, as an iterated integral including both variables?

Let $\large{I} = \Large \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \normalsize f_y(y)\  dy$ for any continuous, differentiable $ f_y: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$

Now, does (2) generally hold, $\forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ ?
$$\tag{2}
I^2 = \left( \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \normalsize f_y(y)\  dy\ \right) \left( \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \normalsize f_x(x)\  dx\ \right) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_y(y)f_x(x) dy\ dx $$

or is result(1) specific to the particular function $e^{-(y^2)/2}$?

Please show the work or reasoning behind how and why this transformation is valid.

Comment: If $\displaystyle \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \normalsize f_y(y)\  dy\ \right)$ converges, it is a constant, let's call it $a$. Then $$\begin{align} \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \normalsize f_y(y)\  dy\ \right) \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \normalsize f_x(x)\  dx\ \right)&=a\left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \normalsize f_x(x)\  dx\ \right)\\ &=\left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} a\normalsize f_x(x)\  dx\ \right)\\&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_y(y) dy\right)f_x(x)  dx, \end{align}$$for similar reasons you can now get the $f_x(x)$ inside the integral on $y$.

Comment: Integrals are essentially sums (in view of Riemann sum). Thus it is not so bad to say that the questioned identity holds because $$(a+b)(c+d) = a(c+d)+b(c+d) = (ac+ad)+(bc+bd).$$

Comment: We must be looking at the exact same textbook. I saw this in the proof that the normal distribution is a pdf, searched for "multiplying two integrals together," and landed right here.

Comment: Read Fubini's Theorem. Try either Wikipedia or Wolfram MathWorld for quick easy read.

Comment: @GitGud what are those "similar reasons"? I don't get it

Comment: @MoranReznik You can replace $a$ with the integral that uses $x$ as its bound variable.

Comment: what is the textbook you'r using

Answer (score 60):

Note first, that for any integrable $f \colon \def\R{\mathbb R}\R \to \R$ and any $\alpha \in \R$ we have
$$ \int_\R \alpha f(x)\, dx = \alpha \int_\R f(x) \, dx $$
Now note that with $\alpha := \int_\R f(y)\, dy$ (this depends on $f$, but given $f$ it is a constant) this gives
$$ \int_\R  \left(\int_\R f(y)\, dy\right)\, f(x)\, dx = \int_\R f(y)\, dy  \cdot \int_\R f(x)\, dx $$
Now, for every *fixed* $x \in \R$, we apply the above again, now for $\alpha = f(x)$ (which is not depending on $y$), giving
$$  \left(\int_\R f(y)\, dy\right)\, f(x) =  \int_\R f(x)f(y)\, dy $$
altogether
$$ \int_\R  \int_\R f(y)f(x)\, dy\, dx = \int_\R f(y)\, dy  \cdot \int_\R f(x)\, dx $$

Comment: why is the second line true? Where you shifted the dy from inside to outside

Comment: Because $\int f(y) dy$ is a constant with respect to x, and you can use the first line to move it outside the integral with respect to x.

Comment: @Dargscisyhp To be pedantic, the integral IS a constant (not just a constant with respect to $x$)

Comment: @masiewpao Sure. But to do what we've done, it's sufficient to be independent of $x$. And any constant is especially constant with respect to $x$.

Comment: @martini I really don'y understand the transition from line 2 to 3... the verbal explanation is not clear enough for my level, probably

Comment: @MoranReznik $\int f(y)dy$ is a constant. So you can take it outside the integral sign.