# Exchanging integral and product

Tags: integration, exponential-function, factoring

Why does $$ \int_{\Bbb R^{3N}}\Bigg[\prod_i^{3N} e^{x_i} \Bigg] d^{3N}x $$ factor into $$ \prod_i^{3N}  \Bigg[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{x_i}  dx_i \Bigg]$$
c.f. ideal gas in canonical ensemble in statistical physics.  Is this a property of the exponential function?  If so, can someone point me to it's definition?

Comment: Apply the argument of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/549923/how-the-product-of-two-integrals-is-iterated-integral-int-cdot-int-iint) answer $3N$ times

Comment: It is Fubini's theorem, but applied in a non-legit way, since all the integrals $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{x_i}\,dx_i$ are divergent.