# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{a}e^{-x^{3}}dx$ using spherical coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, spherical-coordinates

**(Motivation)** I made this improper integral for fun:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{a}e^{-x^{3}}dx = \frac{1}{3}\Gamma\left(\frac{a+1}{3}\right)$$

where $\Re(a) > -1$. After struggling with various integration techniques, I thought of using spherical coordinates.

**(Question)** Is there a way to prove that equation without enforcing spherical coordinates as I did below?

**(Attempt)** Let the integral in question be $I$. Then

$$
\begin{align}
I =& \int_{0}^{\infty}x^{a}e^{-x^{3}}dx \\
=& \frac{2}{3}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\frac{2a-1}{3}}e^{-x^{2}}dx \tag{1}\\
I^3 =&  \frac{8}{27}\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}-y^{2}-z^{2}}\left(xyz\right)^{\frac{2a-1}{3}}dxdydz \cr
=& \frac{8}{27}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\rho^{2}}\left(\rho^{3}\cos\theta\sin\theta\sin^{2}\phi\cos\phi\right)^{\frac{2a-1}{3}}\rho^{2}\sin\phi d\rho d\theta d\phi \tag{2}\\
=& \frac{8}{27}\int_{0}^{\infty}\rho^{2a+1}e^{-\rho^{2}}d\rho\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\cos\theta\right)^{\frac{2a-1}{3}}\left(\sin\theta\right)^{\frac{2a-1}{3}}d\theta \cr
&\cdot \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\sin\phi\right)^{\frac{4a+1}{3}}\left(\cos\phi\right)^{\frac{2a-1}{3}}d\phi \tag{3}\\
=& \frac{8}{27}\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left(a+1\right)}{2}\cdot\frac{B\left(\frac{a}{3}+\frac{1}{3},\frac{a}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\right)}{2}\cdot\frac{B\left(\frac{2a}{3}+\frac{2}{3},\frac{a}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\right)}{2} \tag{4}\\
=& \frac{1}{27}\cdot\Gamma\left(a+1\right)\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{a}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\right)^{2}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{2a}{3}+\frac{2}{3}\right)}\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{2a}{3}+\frac{2}{3}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{a}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\right)}{\Gamma\left(a+1\right)} \tag{5}\\
=& \frac{1}{27}\Gamma\left(\frac{a}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\right)^{3} \cr
\therefore I =& \frac{1}{3}\Gamma\left(\frac{a+1}{3}\right). \cr
\end{align}
$$
Explanations:

$(1)$: Substitute $x \mapsto x^{2/3}$

$(2)$: [Employ spherical coordinates](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calciii/tisphericalcoords.aspx)

$(3)$: [Product of multiple integrals is iterated integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/549923/how-the-product-of-two-integrals-is-iterated-integral-int-cdot-int-iint)

$(4)$: A property of the [Beta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Properties)

$(5)$: A property of the [Beta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Properties)

Comment: no need for such a roundabout approach. Just make the change of variables $t=x^3$ in the original integral.

Comment: @peek-a-boo That's a much easier approach. I don't know how I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u=x^3$, the integral becomes

$$I=\frac13\int_0^\infty u^{\frac{a-2}{3}}e^{-u}~du=\frac13\Gamma\left( \frac{a+1}{3}\right)$$